# Can't add badge parameter to FCM notification json Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Node.js to send FCM's to my iOS app. Everything is working fine until I specify a `badge` parameter. Then I get this error:

```
errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
    message: `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "badge" at 'message.notification': Cannot find field.`
},
  codePrefix: 'messaging'
```

Sample Code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("file/path/to/service/account/json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

const registrationToken = 'notProvidingActualRegistrationTokenForSecurityReasons';


const message = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Hello',
        body: 'Welcome from the Cyber-webs',
        badge: "9",
    },
    token: registrationToken
};


admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Success")
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error Sending Message", error)
    })
```

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.notificationmessagepayload) say that the badge value should be a `string`, by the way. I don't understand why it's not an `int`. Also, why do we need to provide a badge value in the first place? It seems like this should be handled by the OS...

Answer (score 1):

The message `.json` structure is this:

```
const message = {
    notification: {
        title: "Title",
        body: "Body",
     },
     apns: {
         payload: {
            aps: {
                badge: 4,
            }
         }
    },
    token: registrationToken
 };
```